# Is there a construction with a form of "to be" and a past participle?

Tags: tenses, past-participles

In researching a [question](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1396799) on another site, I was trying to find out if the following sentence was using a compound verb:

- You are prepared to graduate.

My assumption had been that it was, but another poster stated that "prepared" was being used as an adjective.  I found that there is a **present progressive tense** that uses "to be" and a present participle:

- You are preparing to graduate.

I have not been able to find a matching tense that uses the past participle, so I am assuming the poster is correct.

My inner word nerd is puzzled at this imbalance.  Would someone please explain?

Comment: Passive constructions use _be_ with a past participle. In this particular example, though, I would agree that _prepared_ is a regular predicative adjective rather than a past participle used in a passive construction. But the grey area between the two is considerable.

Comment: The test for a real Passive Construction is whether you can have an agent _by_-phrase. _He was prepared for the ritual by his guru_ is a Passive transform of _His guru prepared him for the ritual._ Can you put _by your college_ before _to graduate_ and still keep the same sense in _You are prepared to graduate_? I couldn't; so this isn't a Passive, at least not in my idiolect.

Comment: BTW, the the term is ***Construction***, not "Tense". English  only has Present Tense and Past Tense; everything else is a construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh, okay.  Thank you for the correction.  Sigh, I'm going to have to learn to not say "future tense"?  That is going to be rough!

Comment: _Will_ is just another modal auxiliary verb, and they all refer to the future.

Comment: By what logic or grammatical system is the following statement considered correct: *'If "prepared" is an adjective, then "to graduate" would be the noun being modified.'*

Comment: @AlanCarmack Must have been the logic of the brain frat.  Unnecessary and incorrect text deleted.

Comment: *That will/must/might/can/could/should be John at the door this second* doesn't refer to future time @JohnLawler

Comment: No, it doesn't, but then modals don't generally; however they can, since they're basically untensed, except for things like not being able to give an order to someone in the past (which is why _must_ refers to present or future in its deontic senses). The point is that _time_ is not the same thing as _tense_; time is a physical/perceptual phenomenon, whereas tense is a grammatical term, referring to an inflectional category that English modal auxiliary verbs no longer possess. Not even _will_.

Answer (score 2):

You are prepared- here "prepared" is an adjective meaning you fullfilled all necessary conditions to graduate.
You are preparing - this is the present continuous meaning action in progress, you are making the necessary preparations but you are not ready yet.